# TYPO3 PageLayoutView get values from foreign table

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x, typo3-tca

I managed to build a Slider (as own content element) and on the table "tt_content" i have a column which reads the records of the table "slider" and it only gives back the number of the records.

Now, when i create a slider element, on the backend layout, i would like to have a list with the images that are currently on display to this particular slider element. Like this:

[image: Images]

Now on my **SliderPreviewRenderer.php** i have the following

```
public function preProcess(
      PageLayoutView &$parentObject,
      &$drawItem,
      &$headerContent,
      &$itemContent,
      array &$row
   )
   {
      if ($row['CType'] === 'slider') {
        $headerContent = '<strong>' . $parentObject->CType_labels[$row['CType']] . '</strong><br/>';
        $itemContent .= '<p class="title">Images:</p>';
        $itemContent .= $parentObject->linkEditContent($parentObject->getThumbCodeUnlinked($row, 'tt_content', 'slider') . '<br />');

         $drawItem = false;
      }
   }
```

Now i just read the column that it is located on the tt_content (i guess). With this code **i only get the first image** and nothing else.

**The second** thing i would like to have, are the settings. The settings are saved on a different table. How can i get the settings too? The settings are saved on the table "slidersettings". I do not have a code for that, because i have no idea how i can achieve that. The foreign key for the slidersettings is the "slider_settings_relation" and it gives back an integer. The relation is 1-1.

Could you please enlighten me on how i can do that? I have been around the web to search for the solution, but it seems that no one had such a question yet.

Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

I guess the table slider is not directly pointing to the image reference but to a record that itself contains references to images. So with your current code you won't get back the expected result, since it just contains the number of connected sliders, which can not directly be resolved as a file reference.

So you should fetch the sliders connected to that field first to get the actual file reference fields, then generate a single thumbnail for each of them and finally put it into a collection of thumbs to be linked as is already done in your code.

So you might want to take a look into `\TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\Hooks\PageLayoutView\ImagePreviewRenderer`

which makes use of

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Backend\Utility\BackendUtility::resolveFileReferences
```

for exactly that purpose.
It is even based on the same hook you are working with, so it should be working the same way.

Comment: I am aware of that. I know i can not get all the images because they belong to another table, and this code point to the table tt_content. I am just asking how i can readjust my code so i will take the images from the slider with the specific ID